# Python library installation-pypm

Tags: python, eclipse, stepic

I installed the [stepic](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/stepic/) library using Active State. What I did is as follows:

1. Downloaded Active State.
2. Ran the command `pypm install stepic` in the command line.

It was installed successful and I was able to import it successfully in the command line python interpreter. The problem is that I cannot import it into Eclipse. I am using PyDev to code. I know that eclipse needs the path of the library so that it can use it so I tried to install stepic again and it says:

```
skipping "stepic"; already installed at "%APPDATA%\Python" (2.7)
```

On checking the app data path using:

```
import os
print os.getenv('APPDATA')
```

I got the app data path but on going to it I could not find stepic.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the path when I went to `AppData/Roaming`. There was a Python27 folder there and I simply pasted the necessary files into the Python27 folder in the C drive and added the path.